# Scala Actor Based Web Server

Tags: scala, akka

Im trying to implement an incredibly basic Web Server in Scala, based on Akka Actors.

The issue I am having is that the first request I make on my browser works perfectly fine, but then the rest are sporadic, sometimes loading the browser page response again fine, sometimes not doing anything at all. I am wondering if I am closing something incorrectly or just creating a ton of free roaming actors that never stop.

Relevant code:

```
def startHttpServer(port: Int) = {
  try {
    val system = ActorSystem("BasicServerSystem")
    val requestActor = system.actorOf(Props[HttpRequestActor], name = "requestActor")
    val server = new ServerSocket(port)
    logger.info(s"BasicServer listening on port $port")
    while (true) {
      val socket = server.accept()
      requestActor ! socket
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => logger.error(e.getMessage)
  }
}

class HttpRequestActor extends Actor {
  final val logger = Logger.createLogger(classOf[HttpRequestActor])

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case sock: Socket =>
      try {
        val requestId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
        val responseActor = context.actorOf(Props[HttpResponseActor], name = s"responseActor$requestId")
        responseActor ! sock
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => logger.error(e.getMessage)
      }
  }
}

class HttpResponseActor extends Actor {
  final val logger = Logger.createLogger(classOf[HttpResponseActor])

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case sock: Socket =>
      try {
        val out = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream)
        val date = new Date()
        out.println("Received on " + date)
        out.close()
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => logger.error(e.getMessage)
      } finally {
        sock.close()
      }
  }
}
```

Also of note, I am not sure of where to close the socket. Am I on the right track here, or is this a terrible use case for Actors?

Comment: The first issue I see is that you should start a new requestActor from a pool each time a request come in (otherwise the same one answers all the requests, which may be quite a bottleneck). The other thing is I recall a Spray library that was designed to handle HTTP communication, but don't remember the name. You could check it out if you're interested in the topic. Also, don't forget to close the socket after the reply is sent because it prevents the second `accept()`.

Comment: [akka.io](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/io.html) module uses similar approach. You can check out what they've done so far [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/io).

Comment: Look at http://spray.io/ . These guys basically did what you trying to archieve.

Comment: akka.io is the next version of spray.io following Typesafe's acquisition of spray.

Comment: Is there a better way to spawn off new actors than what Im doing, which is creating a random UUID and tagging it on the actor name?

Answer (score 0):

You are responding to new TCP sessions and not to new HTTP requests. Since browsers cache TCP sessions, you may not receive a new socket connection every time you send a new request. When you start a new browser instance, you will definitely get a new socket connection and you can respond (as you have noticed). When you refresh an existing browser, whether a new TCP session gets opened or not depends on timeouts in the browser.

Comment: How would I respond to each new HTTP request instead? Or is that not what I want to do?

Comment: Well, you need to add a HTTPSessionActor which reads from the socket, parses the content to determine the HTTP request being sent and then handle it appropriately. Unless you are doing this as an assignment, you should just use spray or similar http library which does all this for you.